# How to show two view on single screen using Viewpager in react-native

Tags: react-native, viewpagerindicator

I am using rn-viewpager

I want a view like this:

[image]

but I am getting it like this :

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 <IndicatorViewPager
            style={{flex:1,width:60}}
            onPageSelected={(position) => this.onChangeRound(position)}
        >
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center'}}
                       source={this.state.firstRound}
                />
            </View >

            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center' }}
                       source={this.state.secondRound}
                />
            </View >
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center' }}

                       source={this.state.thirdRound}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center' }}
                       source={this.state.fourthRound}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',

                    resizeMode:'center' }}
                       source={this.state.fifthRound}
                />

            </View>

        </IndicatorViewPager>
```

Please Ignore the 'SCROLL' text.

I want 2 images at a time in my screen one active and one inactive and on scrolling it should change. Here everything happens properly except (2 images come on one screen)